# SQL Server - Finding Number patterns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've been looking at this this for the last hour and just can't seem to find a way to do it, I'm sure its pretty simple but my google and reading skills have failed me.

All I need to do is to find ascending and descending numerical patterns in a field.

Like in this pseudo-SQL Code:

```
select * where col = '123456' or '23456' or '7654' or '987654321'
```

Most of the pattern methods using `LIKE` seem to be around placement of characters/numbers rather than the specific ordering,

I've started trying to create a query than takes the first character and compares it to the next one but this seems really ineffective and inefficient as it would need to take each field in the column run the query and return it if it matches.

I've managed to find a way to get it if its a repeated character but not if its an increase or decrease.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show sample data and your desired output?

Comment: Hi Tim,
here's a small sample and expected output

`4141243,
4290577,
98765432,
78635389,
4141243,
22222,
4290046,
55555555,
4141243,
6789,
77777,
45678,
4294461,
55555,
4141243,
5555`
 
so the return from this would be 6789 and 98765432, there is no length criteria (other than the potential Maximum of 12 characters but the number can be between 1-12 characters long)
edit -sorry thats a bit of an eyesore to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option could be something like this:

```
Declare @Table table (col int)
Insert into @Table values
(4141243),(4290577),(98765432),(78635389),(4141243),(22222),(4290046),(55555555),(4141243),(6789),(77777),(45678),(4294461),(55555),(4141243),(5555)

Declare @Num table (Num int);Insert Into @Num values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)

Select Distinct A.*
  From @Table A
  Join (
        Select Patt=replicate(Num,3) from @Num
        Union All
        Select Patt=right('000'+cast((Num*100+Num*10+Num)+12 as varchar(5)),3) from @Num where Num<8
        Union All
        Select Patt=reverse(right('000'+cast((Num*100+Num*10+Num)+12 as varchar(5)),3)) from @Num where Num<8
       ) B on CharIndex(Patt,cast(col as varchar(25)))>0
```

Returns

```
Col
5555
6789
22222
45678
55555
77777
55555555
98765432
```

**

> Think RUMMY 500.  A groups or runs of 3.  For example 123 or 321 or
>   333 would be a hit.

**

Comment: Thanks,  I haven't had a chance to try this yet but it looks sound and solves both of the rules I'm looking for in one solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can put regular expression inside your LIKE quotes.
Ascending:

```
^(?=\d{4,10}$)1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?0?$
```

Descending:

```
^(?=\d{4,10}$)9?8?7?6?5?4?3?2?1?0?$
```

d{4,10} here is possible value length, between 4 and 10 symbols.
Won't be fast, most likely.

You can check how it works on http://rubular.com/.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention you will have to do a MS SQL Server CLR integration first. By default, MSSQL Server does not fully support RegEx.

This article describes how to create and use extensions for the LIKE (Transact-SQL) clause that supports Regular Expressions.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server

Comment: Hi,  Thanks I've given it a go and it doesn't return any results, however it may be I need to change something for it to use Regex its not something I've used myself before as I didn't think it was supported in TSQL

Comment: Won't those match sequences with gaps in? So ^(?=\d{4,10}$)1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?0?$ matches 24567.